# SQL Server While Statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I run the following query like this :

```
WHILE (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, disburse_date, 112) FROM TEST_LOOP) <> 201701
BEGIN
    UPDATE TEST_LOOP
    SET disburse_date = DATEADD(DD, 14, disburse_date)

    SELECT * FROM TEST_LOOP

    IF (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, disburse_date, 112) FROM TEST_LOOP) = 201701
        BREAK
END
```

And I get the following error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've tried to evaluate my query and not yet solved. Any advice will be appreciate.

Thanks..

Comment: Your code has so many problems, there is no place to begin.  Ask another question and (1) provide sample data; (2) show the results you want; and (3) explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to update all records in the table so all of them have `disburse_date` reaching Jan2017?

Comment: @ydoow Yes.. Is it possible if using while statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update all records so the `disburse_date` is reaching Jan2017.

To make it more readable I would create a function first.

```
-- function to return a date reaching Jan2017 with an incremental of 14 days from input date
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateReaching201701
(    
    @in_date AS DateTime    
) 
RETURNS DateTime 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @out_date AS DateTime
    SET @out_date = @in_date

    WHILE (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6),@out_date,112) != 201701) 
    BEGIN
            set @out_date = DATEADD(day, 14, @out_date)
    END

    RETURN @out_date
END
```

Then, apply normal update statement. The additional `WHERE` clause is to make sure all records are prior Jan2017 to avoid an infinite loop.

```
UPDATE TEST_LOOP
SET disburse_date =  dbo.fn_DateReaching201701(disburse_date)
WHERE disburse_date < '2017-02-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
UPDATE TEST_LOOP
    SET TGL_AWAL_KREDIT = DATEADD(DAY, 14, TGL_AWAL_KREDIT)
    WHERE TGL_AWAL_KREDIT < '20170101';
```

Note:  There is no `WHILE` loop.

Comment: I want to loop the day until reach January 2017. Date sample in TGL_AWAL_KREDIT field is '2015-05-27 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: @AfifPratama . . . There is no reason to loop, if a set-based approach solves the problem.